# How can I get this word : There are 4 positive and 3 negative values in the list. (how can I find the number of positive and negative values?)

Tags: assembly

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
LIST    WORD    1200, -209, -900, 501, -480, 200, 240, 0
STR1    BYTE    "There are ", 0
STR2    BYTE    " positive and ", 0
STR3    BYTE    " negative values in the list. ", 0
POSI    BYTE    0
NEGE    BYTE    0


.CODE
MAIN PROC
        MOV     ECX, LENGTHOF LIST
        MOV     ESI, OFFSET LIST
        
L1:     MOV     EAX, [ESI]
        CMP     EAX, 0
        JG      L2
        INC     NEGE
        ADD     ESI, TYPE LIST
        LOOP    L1
        JMP     L3

L2:     INC     POSI
        ADD     ESI, TYPE LIST
        LOOP    L1

L3:     MOV     EDX, OFFSET STR1
        CALL    WRITESTRING

        MOV     EAX, [POSI]
        CALL    WRITEINT

        MOV     EDX, OFFSET STR2
        CALL    WRITESTRING

        MOV     EAX, [NEGE]
        CALL    WRITEINT

        MOV     EDX, OFFSET STR3
        CALL    WRITESTRING

        CALL    CRLF
        EXIT
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

It said that need to have a same size

Error   A2022   instruction operands must be the same size